# SQL Lab Query Assistance

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
CNum    DNum    RNum    Quant   Price
C100    D1      R10     2       8.99
C100    D1      R40     7       9.99
C200    D3      R10     4       16.99
C200    D3      R20     2       15.99
C200    D3      R30     2       17.99
C200    D3      R40     5       19.99
C200    D3      R50     6       18.99
```

Hey guys, the above table is Named "Orders."  I have a few queries I'm trying to solve for a Lab for a Database Management class I'm currently taking.  A few of these queries are giving me some issues, if some of you wouldn't mind helping me out or walking me through some that would be great.  The one I'm stuck on now is stated

"Get customer numbers (CNum) for customers that ordered dish D1 from some restaurant in a quantity greater than the average quantity of dish D1 for that restaurant."

another that I am having some trouble with is quite similar

"Get restaurant numbers (RNum) for restaurants that have orders of dish D1 in an average quantity less than the greatest quantity for any dish ordered from restaurant R10"

I gave #2 here a shot and came up with the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT O.RNum
FROM Orders AS O
WHERE (O.DNum = 'D1') 
AND EXISTS 
        (SELECT AVG(O.Quant) AS AvgQuant
         FROM Orders AS O         
         WHERE EXISTS
                      (SELECT MAX(O.Quant) AS MaxQuant
                       FROM Orders AS O
                       WHERE (O.RNum = 'R10')))
```

With that in mind I currently believe this query to be incorrect due to the fact that I have not specified that the AvgQuant must be LESS THAN the MaxQuant, and am unsure of what the correct syntax would be.  So my question here would be, how do I express that the AvgQuant must be less than the MaxQuant, and we have not used joins yet in this class.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions at the same time. If you feel like you need help with all these issues, you can ask a separate question for all of them, though they will all need to be self-contained and properly asked. Keep the [how to ask homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) in mind, we like an attempt and a specific question. I'm only seeing that for #2.

Comment: Also, please either remove the MySQL tag or the MS-Access tag, it's unlikely you're using both (or explain how you're using both)

Comment: gotchya, will update now

Comment: Anyone have some input?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:

Build an aggregate query that returns the average quantity for each restaurant and dish.

Build an aggregate query that returns the sum quantity for each customer and restaurant and dish.

Build a query that joins the first two on the restaurant and dish fields.
`SELECT Query2.CNum, Query2.RNum, Query2.DNum, Query2.Cust_Rest_Dish_Sum
FROM Query2 INNER JOIN Query1 ON (Query2.DNum = Query1.DNum) AND (Query2.RNum = Query1.RNum)
WHERE (((Query2.Cust_Rest_Dish_Sum)>[Rest_Dish_Avg]));`

Without JOIN clause:
`SELECT Query2.CNum, Query2.RNum, Query2.DNum, Query2.Cust_Rest_Dish_Sum, Query1.RNum, Query1.DNum
FROM Query2, Query1
WHERE (((Query2.Cust_Rest_Dish_Sum)>[Rest_Dish_Avg]) AND ((Query1.RNum)=[Query2].[RNum]) AND ((Query1.DNum)=[Query2].[DNum]));`

The data sample seems inadequate to test the query. No records will return. So I added another record and it is the only customer returned in the query.
`CNum   DNum   RNum    Quant    Price
 C200   D1     R10     5        22.49`

Consider this for question 2 - no join used but really should:
`SELECT DISTINCT Query4.RNum, Query4.DNum, Query4.AvgOfQuant, Query3.MaxOfQuant
FROM (SELECT Orders.RNum, Max(Orders.Quant) AS MaxOfQuant
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Orders.RNum
HAVING (((Orders.RNum)="R10")))  AS Query3, (SELECT Orders.RNum, Orders.DNum, Avg(Orders.Quant) AS AvgOfQuant
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Orders.RNum, Orders.DNum)  AS Query4
WHERE (((Query4.DNum)="D1") AND ((Query4.AvgOfQuant)<[MaxOfQuant]));`

Comment: Yea that isn't the complete table, I deleted some of the data to save space in the thread, is there a way to accomplish this without using joins?

Comment: Not that I am familiar with but then I've never seen EXISTS used in Access query.

Comment: Joining queries and tables is quite basic and Access query builder makes it simple. I am amazed not yet covered in the course. Copy/paste my suggestion into SQL View then switch to Design View. I did get something for second question without joins. See revised answer.

Comment: And I figured out something for the first question not using joins.